# Saving and loading UIImage data causes huge memory issues

Tags: ios, uiimage

I have a working program but am experiencing issues with 'heap memory growth' 
I have narrowed it down to these methods below

Basically i have taken an image from the gallery , imported it into my app , and am using a method to ' re-load ' it every time the user visits the page

I need to do this with 7 images so the memory management is imperative

```
     ///saves the image ///
     if(imagepicked==2)
    {
     NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,    NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

     NSString *filename = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"face.png"];

     [imageData writeToFile:filename atomically:NO];


///loads the image ///
     NSString *cachedImagePath3 = [cachedFolderPath1         stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"face.png"];
     UIImage *image3 = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:cachedImagePath3]];

     newfacebookimage.image = image3;
```

It all works ok , but causes large memory issues

I have tried to use NSuserdefaults also but cant get the code right.
Thanks

Comment: This code, by itself, won't cause a problem (unless the image dimensions far exceed the screen dimensions). I wonder, though, why you're re-saving the image you just loaded, as that seems inefficient. I can only imagine that you're doing that if you're altering the image, so I'd check to make sure that routine is ok. But I wonder if you have some broader memory problem, such as strong reference cycle in your view controller? Have you confirmed that when the view controller is dismissed, that its `dealloc` method really called? Bottom line, the root of the problem rests elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap each load& save in autoreleasepools to reduce the peak

```
@autoreleasepool {
    ... memory intensive work
}
```